# How do I better authenticate Ajax request as being from my site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page on my website that makes several requests to an API I have built. The ajax requests provide a few variables and the API queries a database and returns the proper info back to the requesting page. For security measures I am attempting to use a php session variable and http headers in the ajax request to make sure that only my script can request information from the API. My results however are inconsistent.

**On the requesting page:**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['AUTHORIZE'] = md5(microtime().rand());
?>

<script>
var sessionAuthorize = "<?php echo $_SESSION['AUTHORIZE'];?>";
</script>
```

**In my javascript file where the request originates:**

```
//sessionAuthorize is available in the function below
 constructFilter:function(one,two){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("authorize", sessionAuthorize);
            },
            url: 'http://www.example.com/ajax_return.php?one='+one+'&two='+two,
            success: function(data) {
               //do some things
            }
    });
 }
```

**Then on my PHP script at ajax_return.php, the API:**

```
session_start();

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZE']) && isset($_SESSION['AUTHORIZE']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZE'] == $_SESSION['AUTHORIZE'] ){
       //do all my processing
    }
    else{
        echo 'access denied!';
    }
```

In my php script I am checking to make sure that both variables are indeed set and then if they are, if they match each other. I get a lot of inconsistent results though where "access denied" comes up. So there must be some flaws in the methodology where the session is getting lost or my logic to check it has some problems.

I think I have the right plan for authentication, I just have a few holes in getting it to work right, or maybe I should be using cookies or something.

Comment: First, use https if you want any level of security at all.  Second, what are you really trying to do? Is login required to access pages?

Comment: I just don't want any joe off the street to be able to go to ajax_request.php and access any information. Bottom line I want ajax_request.php to only run or return information if the request is coming from a place I said it can come from, which in this case is one specific page/script on the site.

Comment: this is pretty close to the idea of how a csrf token works.. i would be inclined to put an expiry time on that token however, so probably not a good idea to use `.rand()` in its generation.. as currently you're just checking for its existence. Perhaps have a look at libraries like: https://code.google.com/p/anticsurf/